# Undefined array key en update datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Este es un sistema para subir información de piezas de arte, ya tengo mucho adelantado, pero al editar lo que hay en la base de datos, no me permite cambiar la imagen; El sistema guarda la imagen en una carpeta y guarda el nombre en la base de datos.

Pero cuando le doy en editar puedo editar todo menos la imagen, por que no guarda ni el nombre o la imagen.
pueden ayudarme por favor o al menos decirme como podría estructurar la lógica del formulario.

```
<?php 

include("bd.php");

if(isset($_POST['Guardar'])){
    
    $codigo=$_POST['codigo'];
    $ciudad=$_POST['ciudad'];
    $localizacion=$_POST['localizacion'];
    $lugar_ex=$_POST['lugar_ex'];
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $nacionalidad=$_POST['nacionalidad'];
    $imagen = $_FILES['imagen'];
    $epoca=$_POST['epoca'];
    $fechado=$_POST['fechado'];
    $autor=$_POST['autor'];
    $tipo_bien=$_POST['tipo_bien'];
    $caracter_bien=$_POST['caracter_bien'];
    $material=$_POST['material'];
    $tecnica=$_POST['tecnica'];
    $medidas=$_POST['medidas'];
    $descrip=$_POST['descrip'];
    $estado=$_POST['estado'];
    $estado_inte=$_POST['estado_inte'];

    if(isset($imagen) && $imagen != ""){
        $tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
        $temp  = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];

       if( !((strpos($tipo,'png') || strpos($tipo,'jpeg') || strpos($tipo,'gif') || strpos($tipo,'webp') ||  strpos($tipo,'jpg')))){
          $_SESSION['mensaje'] = 'solo se permite archivos jpg, jpeg, png, gif y webp';
        echo "solos se permiten archivos jpg, etc ";
          $_SESSION['tipo'] = 'danger';
          header('location:ingresar.php');
       }else{
         $query = "UPDATE crud SET ciudad='$ciudad',localizacion='$localizacion',lugar_ex='$lugar_ex',nombre='$nombre',nacionalidad='$nacionalidad',imagen='$imagen',epoca='$epoca',fechado='$fechado',autor='$autor',tipo_bien='$tipo_bien',caracter_bien='$caracter_bien',material='$material',tecnica='$tecnica',medidas='$medidas',descrip='$descrip',estado='$estado',estado_inte='$estado_inte' WHERE codigo='$codigo'";

         $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

         if($resultado){
              move_uploaded_file($temp,'imagenes/'.$imagen);   
             $_SESSION['mensaje'] = 'se ha subido correctamente';
             $_SESSION['tipo'] = 'success';
             header('location:inven.php');
         }else{
          echo "ocurrio un error";
             $_SESSION['mensaje'] = 'ocurrio un error en el servidor';
             $_SESSION['tipo'] = 'danger';
         }
       }
    }
}


?>
```

al ejecutar me muestra esto, ya intente de todo pero no se que mas hacer.

"Warning: Undefined array key "imagen" in C:\xampp\htdocs\museo2\crud02\update.php on line 13"

este es el código del formulario

```
<form method="POST" action="update.php">
          
<div class="form-group">

         <input type="hidden" class="form-control mb-3" name="codigo" placeholder="Codigo" value="<?php echo $row['codigo']?>">
         <label>Ciudad</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="ciudad" placeholder="Ciudad" value="<?php echo $row['ciudad']?>">
         <label>Localizacion</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="localizacion" placeholder="Localizacion" value="<?php echo $row['localizacion']?>">
         <label>Lugar de exhibicion</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="lugar_ex" placeholder="Lugar de exhibicion" value="<?php echo $row['lugar_ex']?>">
         <label>Titulo o Nombre</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="nombre" placeholder="Titulo o Nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre']?>">
         <label>Nacionalidad</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="nacionalidad" placeholder="Nacionalidad" value="<?php echo $row['nacionalidad']?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
         <label>Fotografia</label>
         <input type="file" class="form-control mb-3" name="imagen">

        
</div>
<div class="form-group">  
         <label>Epoca</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="epoca" placeholder="Epoca" value="<?php echo $row['epoca']?>">
         <label>Fechado</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="fechado" placeholder="Fechado" value="<?php echo $row['fechado']?>">
         <label>Autor</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="autor" placeholder="Autor" value="<?php echo $row['autor']?>">
         <label>Tipo de bien</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="tipo_bien" placeholder="Tipo de bien" value="<?php echo $row['tipo_bien']?>">
         <label>Caracteristicas del bien</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="caracter_bien" placeholder="Caracter de bien" value="<?php echo $row['caracter_bien']?>">
         <label>Material</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="material" placeholder="Material" value="<?php echo $row['material']?>">
         <label>Tecnica Utilizada</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="tecnica" placeholder="Tecnica" value="<?php echo $row['tecnica']?>">
         <label>Medidas</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="medidas" placeholder="Medidas" value="<?php echo $row['medidas']?>">
         <label>Descripcon</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="descrip" placeholder="Descripcion" value="<?php echo $row['descrip']?>">
         <label>Estado de la obra</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="estado" placeholder="Estado de la obra" value="<?php echo $row['estado']?>">
         <label>Estado integridad</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" name="estado_inte" placeholder="Estado Integridad" value="<?php echo $row['estado_inte']?>">
</div>
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['mensaje'])){ ?>
          <div class="alert alert-<?php echo $_SESSION['tipo'] ?> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
         <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['mensaje']; ?></strong> 
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
     </div>
<?php session_unset(); } ?>
<br>
<input type="reset" name="Limpiar" class="btn btn-primary">
         <br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="Guardar" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary">

        </form>
```

Comment: El error está en la linea 13 donde haces la asignación de la variable $imagen = $_FILES['imagen'], hace falta ver como tienes tu formulario en html. Edita la pregunta y adjunta esa parte del codigo

Comment: Ya agregue el codigo del formulario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tu formulario hace falta agregar el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` para que pueda mandar información de la imagen a traves del metodo POST del mismo.

Comment: :0 si era esoooo Ahhhhh graciassss!!!!

Comment: Me alegra que funcionara y no agradezcas fue un gusto